# Custom 301 Redirects using Regex

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I've done some research on this and cannot find an good solution. I come from an ASP.net background and am moving our site to WordPress.

My old portfolio link format is as follows

```
/custom-website-design/airline-aviation/5
```

The same link on the new website will be

```
/custom-website-design/airline-aviation
```

Note the last "**/5**" is not there. On my old site I used this to look up the category on the back end.

Now my question is, in wordpress, using either a plugin or a custom .htaccess file, can I have the site look for

```
/custom-website-design/(ANYTHING)/(NUMERIC)
```

and then have it redirect to

```
/custom-website-design/(ANYTHING)
```

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done using WordPress rewrite module but i'm not an expert.
Anyway, you can also do it using *.htaccess* and *mod_rewrite*.

You can put this code in your htaccess (which has to be in root folder)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^custom-website-design/([^/]+)/[0-9]+$ /custom-website-design/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Note: since you're using WordPress, you have to put this rule **before** WordPress' main rule.
Should look like this finally

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(custom-website-design/[^/]+)/[0-9]*$ /$1 [R=301,L]

# WordPress
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L]
```

Comment: Thank you. That worked perfectly. I had a similar rule using the "redirection" plugin in WordPress but it didn't do anything. I edited the .htaccess as you described and it worked right away. Thanks again!